# GraphLookup using the id property (string compared to ObjectId) using spring data mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Looking for options to use the **graphlookup** pipeline where the **from field** is the string value of the Object Id and the **to field** is Object Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your 'from field' to be stored as ObjectId by adding following annotation:

```
@Field(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
```

Answer (score -1):

Still not possible. and there is no field casting available for $graphlookup